# How can I disable carriage returns within an editable TextArea?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, textarea, carriage-return, restrict

I am simply wanting to stop a user entering carriage returns in a TextArea. I have been experimenting with the 'restrict' property in the TextArea but cant seem to work it out.

I have the following code:

```
<mx:Canvas id="cvs1" label="Panel 1" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete"addEvtListnerOnPlaceText()" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
    <mx:TextArea id="txtP1T1" x="10" y="176" text="{placeName}" width="210" textAlign="center" color="#DC0000" restrict="this is where I need some help"/>
</mx:Canvas>
```

I'm not sure if the restrict property will cover this or not but any help will be much appreciated.

I've now managed to get something working:

```
    private function addEvtListnerOnPlaceText():void{
        txtP1T1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyEventDown);
        txtP1T1.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyEventUp);
    }

    [Bindable]
    public var tempString:String;
    private function onKeyEventDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        var character:String = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);

        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            tempString = txtP1T1.text;
            KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP;
        }

    }
    private function onKeyEventUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        var character:String = String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);

        if (e.keyCode == 13)
        {
            txtP1T1.text = tempString;
        }

    }
```

The only issue now is that if you hold return down, it clears the first carriage return and then keeps adding as long as you hold it down. I need a way to stop this happening without just losing focus on the text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No experience with flex3, but after a cursory investigation based on the idea of using an event-driven algorithm it seems you could utilize [`TextEvent`s](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TextEvent.html) and just remove any newlines/carriage returns in the inputted text before passing to the `TextArea`.

Alternatively, you may want to take a look at [`KeyboardEvent`s](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html).

---

However, it seems that utilizing the restrict property would indeed be simplest, as you can just set it to `"^\r"` and that would exclude carriage returns and only carriage returns from being entered. (Of course I'd recommend using `"^\r\n"` instead, to provide overall newline protection from both carriage returns, linefeeds, and any combination of the two.)

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/TextArea.html#restrict

Comment: The "^\r\n" options sounded like a good one, unfortunately flex doesn't seem to understand that. I also tried blocking the ASCII value; "^\u000D". Also unsuccesful although it will block every other ASCII character. I guess the carriage Return (CR) is not considered a proper character. I guess I need to try the keyboard event. I'll experiment disabling the CR when the text area has focus

Comment: @Michael: Then something must be wrong in the flex3 documentation, as `\r` is listed as one of the escape sequences usable in string literals: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=09_Working_with_Strings_03.html ...What specifically is occurring when you try to use it? Do you get an error, or does it just not prevent you from typing newlines in the TextArea?

Comment: it just doesnt prevent me from typing newlines in the TextArea. I hit return on my keyboard and it goes on to a new line. Very frustrating.